# Планировщик заданий. Запуск нескольких действий

Tags: windows

Я хочу в задании создать несколько действий. Какие аргументы мне нужно указать, чтобы при ошибке одного из действий не останавливалось всё задание?

Answer (score 1):

Сделай несколько заданий. Если задания не зависят друг от друга нет смысла группировать их в одно